# CHCSVWriter .CSV File Output Not Created / Not Appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, csv

I am using Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser tool to write several thousand lines of object data to a .csv file.  When I run my program in the iOS Simulator, the newly created .csv file does not appear in the Xcode Project Navigator as I would have expected.  The following is my applicable code:

```
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *exportFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/ExportData-%@.csv", currentTime];
exportFilePath = [exportFilePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

NSOutputStream *exportStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:exportFilePath append:NO];
NSStringEncoding encodingA = NSUTF8StringEncoding;

CHCSVWriter *csvExportWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithOutputStream:exportStream encoding:encodingA delimiter:','];

for(NSString *x in keysArray)
{
    Object *y = [NSDictionary objectForKey:x];

    [csvExportWriter writeField:y.dataA];
    ....
    [csvExportWriter writeField:y.dataZ];
    [csvExportWriter finishLine];
}

[csvExportWriter closeStream];
```

Am I correct to assume that the file should be created and displayed in the Project Navigator since that is where the NSBundle is? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "Project Navigator" you mean the list of files and resources in Xcode, the CSV file will not show up there, because it's not part of your project.  You're running it in the simulator, which means the file is being created in the application's sandbox, not in your project.

Comment: Hi Dave!

Yeah, that's what I was meaning.  In that case, how can I view the output csv file to confirm that it includes everything and in the format that I expect it to?

I suppose for the time being I will change the path to put it somewhere on the macbook and see if that works.  Ultimately what I need is for the ipad running my app to write a csv file to its own drive which I would then later extract once connected to a computer.

Will try and report back.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay - the OP code seems to be valid.  After changing the path to a location on my computer, the csv appears in the correct directory, so I will change the path back to the ipad's local storage and test to confirm that at some future point.